# How to use ParsePlatform in android app with kotlin efficiently?

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform

Let's say that I want to get the data from my database, and use them for my entire project and update my database when its neccessary. What is the best approach for it?
Should I get query in every activity and fragment and then use them? Should I just call it once and put it in a local database and sync them when I have to? 
What do you usually do?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Local Datastore that is built-in the Parse Android SDK: https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#local-datastore . Long story short you might want to retrieve the data on the fly, as you need it, and cache it in local datastore.